# How may I calculate Accuracy in NLTK KMeans Clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to use NLTK's KMeans Clustering Algorithm. 
It is generally going fine. 
I want to use the Metrics package of NLTK to determine precision,recall and f measure.

I searched for some examples in web and in other references but may be without a clue.

If any one may kindly cite an example or reference. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to evaluate the performance of unsupervised learning i.e. clustering. It entirely depends on why are you trying to cluster in the first place.

Still, I think there are few performance metrics available, like,

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation

Comment: Sometimes people also use B-cubed (http://cs.utsa.edu/~qitian/seminar/Spring11/03_11_11/IR2009.pdf) , e.g. http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W/W14/W14-2211.pdf (disclaimer: I'm a co-author of that paper).

Comment: Interesting, would surely love to try sometime.

Comment: I think purity used to be a common eval metric: For each computed cluster C, let M(C) the true cluster that best matches C. For document d, let C(d) be the computed cluster containing d and let T(d) be the true cluster containing d. Then Purity = fraction of d for which M(C(d)) = T(d).

Comment: There's one b-cubed scorer for an entity clustering task from http://www.nist.gov/tac/2012/KBP/tools/el_scorer.py too =)

Comment: I think this holds true provided you know the clusters before hand. Lot of times I do clustering to find the patterns in the data where I have very little information about the clusters which belongs where.

Comment: Agree. Clustering is unsupervised but the need for "evaluation" makes it "pseudo-supervised".

Comment: Thank you for nice pointers and discussion. I generally juggle with models to learn better. I am presently trying to do label sequence with Cluster. By the way found another good library pattern.

Comment: Can you please share it with us as well?

Comment: Please see [Pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pattern) does not seem to depend on NLTK like [Textblob](https://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/).

Answer (score 0):

Precision, Recall, and thus the F-measure are inappropriate for cluster analysis. **Clustering is not classification, and clusters are not classes**!

Common measures for clustering (if you are trying to compare with existing labels, which does not make a whole lot of sense - if you already know the classes, then use classification and not clustering) are the **Adjusted Rand Index** and its variants.

Comment: Thank you for the your kind reply. But researchers are taking clusters as classes and PoS Tagging or NE are possible through clustering. If we may not take F Measure then what may the common metric to evaluate both classifier and clusters over same problem? But isn't (http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/490/10/clustering/clustering02.r) using confusion matrix in K Means. Please correct if I am misinterpreting it.

Comment: The problem is that there is no 1:1 correspondence of clusters and classes. It's not as if the clustering algorithm would produce e.g. "android" and "apple" classes. There is a reason why the author of that r script put quotation marks around the term "confusion matrix" - while it is computed the same way as you would do in classification, it has a different semantic and must not be evaluated the same way.

Comment: I can only recommend to **not compare clustering and classification results**. It's apples and oranges.